# jekyll plugin not working on local machine

Tags: plugins, jekyll

I have developed a simple filter for jekyll liquid module, and put the code in _plugins directory. but when I run jekyll the plugin doesn't work.

here is the directory that I run jekyll:
https://github.com/alishir/alishir.github.io/tree/dev

here is the plugin code, it return simple string just for test:
https://github.com/alishir/alishir.github.io/blob/dev/_plugins/PersianDate.rb

Answer (score 6):

Finally I found source of the problem, jeykll should run in non-safe mode in order to process plugins, but my _config.yml contains following line that prevent jekyll to process plugins.

```
   safe: true
```

Comment: Perhaps it's because of the types of plugins, this one does not satisfy my similar question.